# Comparing a collection to a collection inside an entity using JPA Queries

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, spring-repositories

I am trying to implement a search on an entity collection field using a string collection. Here's what I have at the moment:

**Product**:

```
@Entity(name = "product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "product_category",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_name")
    )
    private Set<Category> categories;
}
```

**Category**:

```
@Entity(name  = "category")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(40)")
    private String name;

    public Category(String categoryName) {
        name = categoryName;
    }

    public Category() {
    }
}
```

**Filter collection** example:

```
Set<String> categories = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList("new","sale","bestseller"));
```

I also thought to pass a **collection of objects** of the same type as the elements of the collection, in which one of the fields is assigned the desired value. But I do not think that this makes sense since I still have to compare only one field of it:

```
Set<String> categories = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Category("new"), new Category("sale"), new Category("bestseller")));
```

Method in **ProductRepository**:

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM meet m WHERE (:categories IS EMPTY OR :categories IN m.categories")
Page<Meet> findAllByFilters(Pageable pageable, @Param("categories") Set<String> categories);
```

The method is definitely not suitable for this case, since we assume that a collection is a single element, rather than comparing element-wise each of the collections.

Comment: Shouldn't the JPQL query be `SELECT m FROM meet m WHERE (:categories IS NOT EMPTY OR m.categories.name IN (:categories))`?

Comment: As far as I know, JPA forbids to navigate via a collection valued path expression (```m.categories.name``` unacceptable). Probably the problem can be solved using the ```JOIN``` construction. And why is the collection checked for nonemptiness and the ```OR``` keyword is used?

Comment: Just tried the following construction  ```SELECT m FROM meet m JOIN m.categories c WHERE (:categories IS EMPTY OR c.name IN :categories)```, but got following error: ```unexpected AST node: :```

Comment: `IN` parameter must be enclosed by parenthesis. So the query should be `SELECT m FROM meet m JOIN m.categories c WHERE (:categories IS EMPTY OR c.name IN (:categories))`. Also I think collections parameters should not be validated if empty (or not) inside JPQL.

Comment: Parentheses are optional, they were required in older hibernate versions (this was a bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5126).
Regarding the check for emptiness, the error turned out to be exactly in this place, I had to check the ```IS NULL``` instead, passing an un-initialized collection and I was able to get the result. But for a reason not clear to me, page will be filled with the same result. For example, retrieving all entities returns a page with the duplicate first entity, and retrieving products from a specific category returns the product with the lowest id.

Comment: In fact, I have a lot of parameters and they are all optional. In the case of one or three parameters, it would be better to make several methods with different parameters, but not in my case.